# Consider two independent random variables X, Y uniformly distributed on some set A

Tags: probability

Consider two independent random variables $X, Y$ uniformly distributed on some set A.

The density of the uniform distribution on a set $A$ is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1/M(A)   &\text{if }x \in A
\\[1ex] 0& \text{if }x \notin A\end{cases}$$

where $M(A)$ is the area of the set.

Let $B$ be a subset of $A$

> 1) what is the probability $\mathsf P (X\in B,Y \in B)$?

I thought the answer is just  $\left(\dfrac{M(B)}{M(A)}\right)^2$. But Isn't the given information about density function relevant?

> 2) What is the probability $\mathsf P(\text{"Only one of $X, Y$ in $B$"})$

Is the answer : $2\left(\frac{M(B)}{M(A)}\right)\left(1-\frac{M(B)}{M(A)}\right)$?

Can any one please help!

Thank you in advance.

Panda

Comment: Hi Panda, by some set $A$, do you happen to mean some interval?

Comment: @probablyme, No, it is a 2 dimensional plane. you never replied me email. I hate you. :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is *because* you are given the density function, that you know that: $$\mathsf P\{X\in B\} = \int\limits_{x\in B} f(x)\operatorname d x = \dfrac{M(B)}{M(A)}$$
... and by symmetry it is also so for $Y$.

Thus indeed, by independence, we have: $\mathsf P(X\in B, Y\in B) = \left(\dfrac{M(B)}{M(A)}\right)^2$

---

Now, similarly we have $~\mathsf P(X\notin B) ~=~ \dfrac{M(A)-M(B)}{M(A)}$ and thus:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\{X\in B\} \oplus \{Y\in B\}) ~=~& \mathsf P(X\in B, Y\notin B)+\mathsf P(X\notin B, Y\in B) \\[1ex] ~=~& \dfrac{2~M(B)~\big(M(A)-M(B)\big)}{M(A)^2}\end{align}$$

---

**tl;dr** Yes.  That was okay.

Comment: You have been so helpful, thank you for your kindness. :D